# Klein-Gordon PDE infinite line with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, periodic-functions

In two of my mathematical physics textbooks on QFT, when solving the Klein-Gordon equation over the infinite line, the authors (Wald and Parker/Toms) take the Klein-Gordon equation and place the field in a box of length $L$, and then apply periodic boundary conditions: $\phi(-L,t) = \phi(L,t)$. To recover the solution over the real line $-\infty < x < \infty$, they then say one can just take the limit as $L \to \infty$.

I don't understand how this can work. Solving with periodic B.C.'s you'll get eigenfunctions that look like $\sin(a x / L)$, and as $L \to \infty$ these will vanish.

Any ideas on what they are implying with this "convenient mathematical device" as they call it?

Thanks.

Comment: For a rigorous treatment see [Reed and Simon II](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Kz7s7bgVe8gC&printsec=frontcover&dq=reed+simon&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq6p3Ehu3iAhWxCTQIHXS4Ce0Q6AEIODAC#v=onepage&q=free%20quantum%20fields&f=false) Free Quantum Fields, p. 207.